# how can i use Spring boot Securty

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth

have a smal Spring Boot Project it is a REST API for a PHP Project.

the PHP Projece save the Passwords of the user encryptet with BCrypt (Using Pepper)

i use OAuth in my webservice.
To do the thing with OAuth I used the following instructions:
[OAuth whis Spring Boot](https://gigsterous.github.io/engineering/2017/03/01/spring-boot-4.html)

in my test project that works great too
Now I have tried to transfer this to my project. Unfortunately, it does not work there.

```
curl -X POST --user 'gigy:secret' -d 'grant_type=password&username=USERNAME&password=PASSWORD' http://localhost:8080/Api/oauth/token
```

The Answer is:

```
{"timestamp":1513858442975,"status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Bad credentials","path":"/Api/oauth/token"}
```

Unfortunately, I do not know exactly where the problem is. I suspect that it is because I do not hand over Pepper. The PHP application uses a pepper in the hash

OAuth2Config.java:

```
package com.company.webservice.config;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.configurers.ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer;

import com.company.webservice.ApiApplication;

@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OAuth2Config.class);

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("userDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Value("${gigy.oauth.tokenTimeout:3600}")
    private int expiration;

    private String bCryptPepper = "";

    // password encryptor
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() 
    {
        logger.debug("Create Password Encoder ... .. .");
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer configurer) throws Exception 
    {
        logger.debug("Set OAuth Config ... .. .");
        configurer.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        configurer.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception 
    {
        clients.inMemory().withClient("gigy").secret("secret").accessTokenValiditySeconds(expiration)
                .scopes("read", "write").authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token").resourceIds("resource");
    }

}
```

The question is now how I get along with the problem, in the log files is unfortunately not found.
I can also post more code I'm just not sure what you need.

Comment: Where do you build your `AuthenticationManager`? Is your `UserDetailsService` called? And is `Api` your context root?

Comment: yes the API context is right, when i edit that i become an HTML Response whis 404 code

Comment: here: @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager; i think its Spring Magic

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not say exactly if the service is called.
I have written a logger entry in the service. But find no entry in the log

Comment: i think is was not called